# how to copy folder on docker container

Tags: docker

i have docker container ,i want copy `folder of multiple files` on root directory on docker container.

how i can copy folder with multiple files on docker container?

i can copy file on docker container like this code

```
docker cp F:/Projects/marcopacs/db.bak mssql:/var/opt/mssql/backup
```

but i want copy folder with multiple file to root of docker container

please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

better you create folder and cp all files to folder like this code :

```
docker exec -it your-docker-container mkdir /FilesFolder
```

then cp all file folder to FilesFolder like this code :

in folder

```
docker cp pathofyourFolders/. your-docker-container:/FilesFolder/
```

or  cp all file folder in root

```
docker cp pathofyourFolders/. your-docker-container:/.
```

and for check result

```
docker exec -t -i your-docker-container /bin/bash
```

and us  `ls /` and  `ls /FilesFolder` to see you files

Answer (score 0):

Following command will work for it:

```
docker cp F:/Projects/marcopacs/. mssql:/var/opt/mssql/backup/
```

It will copy all the files from folder `marcopacs` into `backup` folder within docker container.

**Note:** Make sure to have `/.` at the end of source folder, then it will copy all the files within that source folder.